# Angular http post response handling

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, arraybuffer

I am developing an app with ionic 3 / angular and I have encountered a little problem. I am making a post request from within a service and I am trying to work with the returned value on a success callback.
I get the following transpilation error:

`Argument of type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Occasion'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.`

The code leading to the error:

```
this.api.post('occasions', occasion).subscribe(occasion => {
    this.myOccasions.unshift(occasion);
    this.myOccasionsChanged.next(this.myOccasions);
  },
```

The list `this.myOccasions` is defined as `private myOccasions: Occasion[];`

My api service post function is defined as:

```
post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
  if (!reqOpts) {
    reqOpts = {};
  }

  let headers = {};
  this.addAccessTokenToHeaders(headers);
  reqOpts.headers = headers;
  return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
```

}

Can you guys please guve me any advice on how to make the types agree? Of course my POST endpoint returns a OccasionDto to work with.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can map the .post() method to transform the data and return what you need (an Occasion)

```
post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any): Observable<Occasion> {
   //etc...
   return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
   .map( data => {
      //do some transformation in the data, to return an `Occasion`
      const newData = /* something here, a function, a new Occasion(args), etc.... */
      return newData;
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually created the ApiService in order to have a possibility to reuse the methods (post, get, update etc.) for different entities. So I do not want to define that this post function returns an Observable of `Occasion` because this function is designed to be used with other entities too

Comment: What you are doing does not make any sense. You can use HttpInterceptors to add the headers you need to you requests (take a look here: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) and then create the services you need, for each kind of object, following a REST pattern. So you don't have to build a "generic" http client, you can build specific ones, with the headers being "added" through the interceptor.

Comment: How do I map between ArrayBuffer and my Occasion object?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution now. I used your advice with the interceptor (cheers!) but still kept the apiService in order to deal with params etc. for me. I used generic types instead and it works good! Check out the answer that I posted

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question. The way I dealt with it was the following:

In my ApiService, I changed method signatures so that they require to specify the expected return type and set response type to 'json', since, acording to angular docs, then the http client will return `Observable<Object>`.

```
 post<T>(endpoint: string, body: any): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, {responseType: 
    'json'});
 }
```

Then, when I call my apiService method I specify what entity I want to get out, as following:

```
this.api.post<Occasion>('occasions', occasion).subscribe(result => {
    this.myOccasions.unshift(result);
    this.myOccasionsChanged.next(this.myOccasions);
  },
```

I think it is pretty neat, although if anyone has anything cleaner / better, please share :)